# Tabs angular show the first tab

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I try to use the Tabs which comes from angular material so I follow the documentation but when I use the piece of code that you find just below the first tab is not displayed when the page has finished loading I am forced to click on it.

official documentation about the tabs links: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

How to make the first tab to be already loaded without me needing to click on it?

**tabs.html**

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar [backgroundColor]="background">
  <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of links"
     (click)="activeLink = link"
     [active]="activeLink == link"> {{link}} </a>
  <a mat-tab-link disabled>Disabled Link</a>
</nav>
```

**tabs.ts**

```
public activeLink  = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define activeLink by index, you define it by value:

```js
  links = ['First', 'Second'];
  activeLink = this.links[0];
```

Please see [the official Stackblitz from Angular](https://stackblitz.com/angular/keyblelydpa?file=src/app/tab-nav-bar-basic-example.ts).